# Error when creating a schema after installing MYSQL on connecting with worklight

Tags: database, ibm-mobilefirst

I am facing problem in creating schema for an app developed on worklight. The USE WRKLGHT command is giving error:

```
CREATE DATABASE WRKLGHT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
GRANT ALL privileges ON WRKLGHT.* TO 'worklight'@'Worklight-host' IDENTIFIED BY 'worklight';
GRANT ALL privileges ON WRKLGHT.* TO 'worklight'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'worklight';
```

Flush privileges;

```
CREATE DATABASE WLREPORT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
GRANT ALL privileges ON WLREPORT.* TO 'worklight'@'Worklight-host'IDENTIFIED BY 'worklight';
GRANT ALL privileges ON WLREPORT.* TO 'worklight'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'worklight';
Flush privileges;
```

USE WRKLGHT;

```
SOURCE <worklight_install_dir>/WorklightServer/databases/create-worklight-mysql.sql;
```

USE WLREPORT;

```
SOURCE <worklight_install_dir>/WorklightServer/databases/create-worklightreports-mysql.sql;
```

What is to be given in  ?
The following error is being reported:

```
ERROR:
Failed to open file '<worklight_install_dir>\WorklightServer\databases\create-wo
rklight-mysql.sql', error: 22
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace <worklight_install_dir> by the installation path of Worklight,
For example /opt/IBM/Worklight if it is where you installed it (on Windows, something like c:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight)